# SSIS How to retrieve a file name when using a Foreach ADO Enumerator

Tags: file, path, ssis, foreach, enumerator

Here is my problem. 
I have a first SQL task that return filepath into a Full result set (ie: \server\myfolder)
I have then a variable , "USER::VAR_SQL" which is a System.Object.

then I connected my Execute SQL Task to a foreach loop Container and
in " Collection" I selected "Foreach ADO Enumerator" and then as ADO object variable ""USER::VAR_SQL" 
in "Variable mappings" I added  USER::filepath as variable.

Now, How can I loop on each USER::VAR_SQL value and then enumerate each file *.txt in the folder? I cannot find the way to get access to the files in myfolder.

Thanks you in advance
Manu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you are "shredding" the ADO resultset. You now need to do the same operation against the filesystem.  Embed a [foreach file enumerator](http://www.sqlis.com/post/Looping-over-files-with-the-Foreach-Loop.aspx) inside the existing foreach ado enumerator and wire it up.

A picture might be more informative
[image]

Comment: OK, you mean : I should embed an other Foreach Loop Container defined as a foreach file enumerator in the one "shredding" the ADO resultset?

Comment: Correct. The outer one reads a row from the SQL query that looks like \\server\share and assigns that to a variable like USER::Path  In the inner ForEach enumerator, use that variable as the folder source via expression (follow the article). The file enumerator is what will give you access to see what's on the file system. Right now, you only have a string that *might* be a path. Using the second enumerator will make it *go*